# Can I switch location providers?

Tags: cyanogenmod, location-services

There are three ways one can get location:

1. GPS only
2. WiFi / Signal
3. 1 + 2

If I choose 2 or 3, my phone tells me that it's going to send my location data to Google.

I know there are other WiFi coverage maps (http://www.openwlanmap.org/). Is there any way to set them up as the location provider (I'm rooted and on Cyanogenmod)?

Comment: Do you really need that, or you just don't want to send data to Google?

Comment: @geffchang both.